# Partial extents for ArcGIS android geodatabase creation

Tags: spatial-database, query, android, feature-layer, arcgis-android

I know how to create and download a geodatabase copy of a `FeatureServer` from arcgis rest services. I also know how to pass `LayerQuery` to the geodatabase task to filter layer objects and features.

Here is my question, in the class `GenerateGeodatabaseParameters` where I define my selected layers, query parameters and extent, how can I have multiple partial extents for my geodatabase? i.e. two separate polygons. Is that even possible?